# Build Netbeans project using Maven commands

Tags: java, netbeans, maven-2

How can I build a Netbeans project by using `pom.xml`?

In Eclipse I have to use following commands to do that:

```
mvn install
```

then

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

What are similar commands to build projects in Netbeans?

Comment: Netbeans has support for maven projects build-in for some time now, maven projects can be opened and build just as native netbeans projects. If that does not work for you then you need to be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import Maven project in Netbeans. Netbeans itself will build your web project.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is: "How to import a Maven based project into NetBeans for development?"

If so, than see [NetBeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven). You should just install the Maven plugin and import the project from `pom.xml`.

P.S. The `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is a bit deprecated. Check out the [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 7 can open Maven projects automatically. In Netbeans just `File->Open Project` and point to the dir with your `pom.xml` in it.